# ReportHistoryLink/ History Field missing "View History" link in Report Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am working on a SharePoint migration project. I have a report library which has a history field. It's not showing "View History" link. It works fine in 2007 site, but, not in 2010. Am I missing any configuration?

Please help. It's very urgent.